# Which rulers, apart from Julius Caesar, used the Caesar cipher?

Tags: julius-caesar, cryptology, caesar

The [Caesar cipher](https://www.telsy.com/the-caesar-cypher/), apparently devised by Julius Caesar to communicate with Cicero in wartime, consists of replacing each letter in the original message with the letter three places after in the alphabet. I understand that Augustus Caesar also used a variant of the Caesar cipher, with a shift of one instead of three, but is there evidence of any other early ruler using this, especially those who lived in the first millennium AD?